# How to decide when to use memory barrier

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, linux-kernel, memory-barriers

As part of writing driver code, i have come across codes which uses memory barrier (fencing). After reading and surfing through Google, learnt as to why it is used and helpful in SMP. Thinking through this, in multi threaded programming we would find many instances where there are memory races and putting barrier in all places would cost system CPU.  I was wondering how to:

1. I know about specific code path which use common memory to access data, do I need memory barrier in all these places?
2. Any specific technique or tip which will help me identify this pitfalls?

This is very generic questions but wanted to get insight on others experiences and any tips which would help to identify such pitfalls.

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/paulmck/perfbook/perfbook.html http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/weakmemory/ Enjoy!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determining the location for the usage of barriers (fences)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446982/determining-the-location-for-the-usage-of-barriers-fences)

Answer (score 1):

Often device hardware is sensitive to the order in which device registers are written.  Modern systems are weakly-coupled and typically have write-combining hardware between the CPU and memory.

Suppose you write a single byte of a 32-bit object.  What is in the write-combining hardware is now A _ _ _.  Instead of immediately initiating a read/modify/write cycle to update the A byte, the hardware sets a timer.  The hope is that the CPU will send the B, C, and D bytes before the timer expires.  The timer expires, the data in the write-combining register gets dumped into memory.

Setting a barrier causes the write-combining hardware to use what it has.  If only slot A is occupied then only slot A gets written.

Now supposed the hardware expected the bytes to be written in the strict order A, C, B, D.  Without precautions the hardware registers get written in the wrong order.  The result is what you expect: Ready!  Fire!  Aim!

Barriers should be placed judiciously because their incorrect use can seriously impede performance.  Not every device write needs a barrier; judgement is called for.