# How can I judge where should I put memory barrier in the code?

Tags: linux-device-driver, memory-barriers

When I am reading ldd3, I get the conception about memory barrier, it is said  that code execution will be reordered, for the reason like caching and compilation optimizations. I think codes that have no dependencies can be reordered to get better peformance, and IO ports registers can not be optimized, because it need contain consistent data. But I can not understand the code below, and is there any rules to follow where should I insert functions like smb(),mb(),barrier()?

For example, in the examples code **short** from ldd3.

```
/*
* Atomicly increment an index into short_buffer
*/
static inline void short_incr_bp(volatile unsigned long *index, int delta)
{
    unsigned long new = *index + delta;
    barrier(); /* Don't optimize these two together */
    *index = (new >= (short_buffer + PAGE_SIZE)) ? short_buffer : new;
}
```

How line before barrier and the line after barrier reordered? I think the latter depends on the former to be executed first to get *new* value.
This really makes me confused.

Comment: My answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446982/determining-the-location-for-the-usage-of-barriers-fences/20476292 describes some general patterns to look out for.because they require memory barriers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memory barriers are used instead of locking for gain better performanse. There are several standard patters, when memory barriers provide needed syncronizaton. You can read, e.g., `Documentation/memory-barriers.txt` from the kernel sources.

In the given example from ldd3 barriers usage is tricker than usual. In the terms of current kernel(as opposite to 2.20+, which is described in ldd3) same intention can be expressed using `ACCESS_ONCE()` macro.

```
unsigned long new = *index + delta;
ACCESS_ONCE(*index) = (new >= (short_buffer + PAGE_SIZE)) ? short_buffer : new;
```

Without bariers, compiler may assign *index *twice*:

```
*index = *index + delta;
if(*index > (short_buffer + PAGE_BUFFER)
    *index = short_buffer;
```

Because `*index` is used in multiple threads as *unprotected invariant*(it shows which buffer region is available), writting intermediate value `*index + delta` into it make invariant, seen by other thread, incorrect. This is prevented by ACCESS_ONCE() macro, which force compiler to generate access(write) to variable only when is is explicetely requested.

Actually, `ACCESS_ONCE` (and barrier in you code) is redudant for variable with `volatile` modifier.