# what does spin_unlock_wait do in linux2.6.11

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

spin_unlock_wait in linux2.6.11 include/asm-i386/spinlock.h looks like this:

```c
#define spin_unlock_wait(x) do { barrier(); } while(spin_is_locked(x))
```

Why do we need a `barrier()` there and how should we use it.

I've learned optimization barrier ensures no compiler's reordering and it can be used as `wmb()`. I've also learned there's memory barrier at `spin_lock()` to ensure as long as we get the lock, we can read valid content. But I'm confused here and I'd like to see a specific condition where `barrier()` in `spin_unlock_wait()` matters.

I think I've understand. `spin_unlock_wait` wants to do exactly the same thing as `spin_lock` does. Because cpu won't reorder two read ops, the `barrier` insures after finding the unlocked state, writes inside the lock are visible now.

I used to think we need a rmb() here, but rmb() should be used to prevent from `Read-Write` reordering not `Read-Read` here.

Comment: I don't know why it is needed, but it has been there since the first appearance of the `spin_unlock_wait(x)` macro in kernel 2.1.36. You will have to check the LKML archives from April 1997 to find out who wrote that macro.

Comment: thanks! I also find [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446982/determining-the-location-for-the-usage-of-barriers-fences) helpful.

Comment: spin_unlock_wait seems pointless. TOCTOU bug generator?

Comment: I agree, I do think `spin_lock` should be used to replace `spin_unlock_wait`.

Comment: It was removed in Linux kernel v4.14 by [commit d3a024abbc438277851c510b51ec9b158821488b](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=d3a024abbc438277851c510b51ec9b158821488b).